# Why is my multi-threading slower than my single threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know a couple of people asked a question similar to this, but I can’t find any response that would make me understand why it's slower.

So, I made a little console program for my own understanding of the threading object in Visual Studio 2013. My CPU is an Intel Core i7 that supply can use multiple threading.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static TimeSpan MTTime;
        static TimeSpan STTime;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();


            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "---------------Multi Process-------------" + Environment.NewLine);

            Thread th1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Process));
            Thread th2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Process));
            Thread th3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Process));
            Thread th4 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Process));

            th1.Start("A");
            th2.Start("B");
            th3.Start("C");
            th4.Start("D");

            th1.Join();
            th2.Join();
            th3.Join();
            th4.Join();

            stopwatch.Stop();
            MTTime = stopwatch.Elapsed ;

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "---------------Single Process-------------" + Environment.NewLine);


            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();

            Process("A");
            Process("B");
            Process("C");
            Process("D");

            stopwatch.Stop();
            STTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;

            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Multi  : "+ MTTime + Environment.NewLine + "Single : " + STTime);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Process(object procName)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(procName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result image:

[image]

We can clearly see that the multi-treading process is total random and the single one just do all presses on after the other, but I don't think this have an impact on the speed.

At first, I thought my thread was just bigger than the process needed for running the program, but after changing for a bigger process the single treading still was still the fastest in a big way. So, do i miss a concept in multi-threading? Or it normal that is slower?

Comment: Writing to the console is an awful test. Try calculating a couple thousand cryptographic hashes in the `Process` loop instead (with a single write to the console at the end) and you'll see a speedup.

Comment: just to add to the really good answer bellow: you will rarely succeed with using Threads - please rather use the higher-level APIs from theTPL, like Tasks, or better yet PLinq and co. (or if you really know what you are doing go on - but no offense but in this case you might want to get into it a bit more first)

Comment: Run the Visual Studio Profiler, and you will see where the application is ineffective. (Hint: `Console`)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the official [Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) documentation

> I/O operations that use these streams are synchronized, which means
>   that multiple threads can read from, or write to, the streams. This
>   means that methods that are ordinarily asynchronous, such as
>   TextReader.ReadLineAsync, execute synchronously if the object
>   represents a console stream

This means that the console class **handles the thread synchronization** so if thread A and thread B are trying to write to the console the console will handle them and only one for time will be able to write. The ***handling logic*** behind it is the reason why it takes longer

**UPDATE**

I suggest you to have a look at [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok!, so if i understand, it cause of teh way the consol handle the threading ? so , i guess if im doing somthing else then writing or reading stuff in console it would work ? right ? let me try this , but im not shure what could be a good test thx a lot ur maing me advance ! :D

Comment: @Kazimar You should use multi-threading when you a lot of data to process with some alghorthim or stuff like that, I also suggest you to have a look at Parallel.ForEach, I'll update my answer. Have a look, and if you consider my answer as the one you were looking for mark as answered!

Comment: Another way to describe this, would be to say that because the console writes need to be threadsafe, it is a serialised resource, and the threads spend a lot of time waiting their turn. If these were disk writes you would buffer them six ways from Sunday.

Answer (score 71):

Note that `Process` writes to the console (and basically does nothing else), and that output to the console (which here acts as a kind of shared resource) is slow and needs to be synchronized with the other threads.

To my understanding, the parallelization you use creates a huge overhead but gains no speedup, because all of the time the threads are apparently mostly waiting for the other process to finish writing to the console.

Comment: Exactly. To the OP: if you want a valid comparison of single-threaded vs multi-threaded implementations of an algorithm, you have to make sure that those implementations can in fact run completely independently of each other. And in particular, they cannot use any shared resources, since that causes the individual threads to have to wait on each other.

Answer (score 4):

One more thing to take into account: you are suffering from overhead for thread creation and join. Also, you might get a slight performance upgrade by using threadpool, take a look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

OK! thx to Assa and Codor to put my mind to the right place! I finaly make a little console programe that show everyting very clairly. Finaly multitreading is a LOT faster when using heavy processing stuff . Just read my code and u gonna understand with ease.

Result :

[image]

Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        //Timer for speed guidance
        static Stopwatch stopwatch;
        //Data i use for generate time
        static List<int> timeData;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            timeData = new List<int> { 1000, 800, 200, 700, 600, 300, 800, 100, 200, 300, 655, 856, 695, 425 };

            ////-------------------------- SINGLE THREAD ------------------------------/////
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("             Single Threading Process            ");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("   Process Time        Thread ID                 ");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();
            //For each normal that use only 1 thread
            foreach(int i in timeData)
            {
                Process(i);
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();
            //Total time that the program take for making the process happen
            Console.WriteLine("*Total : " + stopwatch.Elapsed );

            ////-------------------------- Mulit Multiple ------------------------------/////

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("             Multi Threading Process            ");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("   Process Time        Thread ID                 ");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();
            //for each thats use Multiple thread fr the process (can be made with parallel.invoke or Task Library or Thread Library)
            Parallel.ForEach(timeData, (i) => Process(i));
            //Total time that the program take for making the process happen
            Console.WriteLine("*Total : " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Methode for sumulating long processing
        static void Process( int time)
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();
            //sleep time simulate the IO portion of the process
            Thread.Sleep(time);
            // The loop simulate de algoritme type of precessing
            for (int i = 0; i < time*1000000; i++){}
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine( stopwatch.Elapsed + "         " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());          
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: That's a better "demo" of Multithreading. However note that all your threads use the same stopwatch object. If you want each thread to mesure it's own execution time you should declare a new StopWatch variable in Process(int).

Comment: Your stopwatch only show the difference between the last Start and the first Stop. That's why you have a lot of the same numbers. With threading, each individual process won't be faster. It's the combination of multiple process that will.

Comment: hummm im not shure what u mean ? can u develope more plz :) are u saying that my start / stop watch is at the wrong place in my loop ? cause my multi treadhing is still faster if u see the combination. Or ur just saying a fact about the treadhing and my coding is fine ?

Comment: Please don't post answers that clarify the original question; post edits to the original question. Answers should be only *answers* to the question.

Comment: Ok got it! sry it my first post :)

Comment: In this specific case, please disregard Eric's advice.  Editing your question to apply suggestions made in other answers makes it impossible for future visitors to understand existing answers. However, I don't recommend posting answers of the form, "I tried this other answer and it worked," unless the existing answers failed to fully answer your question (though usually a comment is sufficient in this case).  The ideal way to conclude your StackOverflow experience is to accept the most helpful answer (click the checkbox next to that answer).

Answer (score 0):

Applications will **work faster with multiple threads if and only if the processor is a bottleneck**. Sometimes your disk or RAM are bottlenecks. Most often it's a database or an external service. Adding multiple threads isn't likely to make the code run faster in those cases, quite the contrary, it will often slow execution due to additional synchronization.

If you want to make your code run faster, you must first check what makes it run slowly. **Profile your code. Locate the bottleneck**.

And remember that [*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

In your case the bottleneck - the single most-accessed resource which blocks all actions - is the console output stream. It has a single instance and it works relatively slowly. Even a single core won't be used 100% to print on it as fast as possible.

Comment: yeah i finaly noticed with all my test! and if i run some small process stuff the multi-threading stuff is actualy slower just due to the process it generate it self for making the multi-tread object and everyting.In most case it useless .... unless ur doing stuff that use realy greatly multi-threading ... like network etc.... or big algorithmic stuff.

Comment: Well, not quite an answer to the question, but I am looking for reasons why my app runs slow and this made me think, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete line below, your multithread would be faster.

```
Console.Write(procName);
```

its because the operating system treat Console as a shared resource and just one thread can use a shared resource at a moment.So in this condition, mutlithread speed up would be like a single thread, but multithreading is burdening some additional thread management overhead with no performance gain.