# Why isn't the multithreaded loop faster?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, multiprocessing

I just read [this intro](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#Abstract) to parallel processing with openMP.

I tried the following simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
        // Create an object just to allow the following loops to do something
        std::vector<int> a;
        a.reserve(2000);

        // First single threaded loop
        std::clock_t begin;
        std::clock_t end;
        begin = std::clock();
        double elapsed_secs;

        for(int n=0; n<1000000000; ++n)
        {
                if (n%100000000 == 0) a.push_back(n);
        }

        end = std::clock();

        elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout << "Time for single thread loop: " << elapsed_secs << std::endl;

        // Second multithreaded loop
        begin = std::clock();
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int n=0; n<1000000000; ++n)
        {
                if (n%100000000 == 0) a.push_back(n);
        }

        end = std::clock();
        elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout << "Time for multi thread loop: " << elapsed_secs << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

which has been compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 -o a a.cpp -fopenmp` which outputs

```
Time for single thread loop: 3.9438
Time for multi thread loop: 3.94977
```

- Do I misunderstand how to parallelize in C++
- Do I misunderstand how to compile?
- Is the code parallelize but the improvement in speed is not-noticable for whatever reason?

Note that I have 12 cores (and no big process currently running) on my machine.

Comment: could it be an optimization problem?

Comment: You have a dependency as `a` is common between each loop processing.

Comment: What is faster, flip a switch thousand times or have thousand people who each flip same switch once? I am surprised that parallel version is not slower. Guess OMP did the sane thing and didn't spawn any additional threads.

Comment: I tried to replace `a.push_back(n);` by `std::cout << n << std::endl;` but there still no difference in performance

Comment: @Remi.b `g++ -std=c++11 -o a a.cpp -fopenmp ` -- You used no optimizations on that command line.  Where is `-O3` or similar to turn on the optimizations?

Comment: Ok, so instead of pushing the same switch named "a" a thousand times, you are trying to push a switch named "std::cout" a thousand times. Hint: std::cout is a single object.

Comment: I tried using optimizations but while it improves computational time, there is still no difference in time between the two loops. The "people switching a light" analogy seem to be the answer but I fail to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not measuring real time but cpu time with `std::clock`. Better use `std::chrono` as some other answer suggested.

Or for a quick test without changing your code, try this in a shell:

```
date; time ./a; date
```

This was the output:

> jue dic  1 23:12:57 CET 2016
>
> Time for single thread loop: 2.99741
>
> Time for multi thread loop: 4.55788
>
> real  0m4.184s
>
> user  0m7.556s
>
> sys   0m0.000s
>
> jue dic  1 23:13:01 CET 2016

The time differs from your output. The real time it's about 4s in my pc and not 7.5s as in the output from your program.

You should read the docs about  [`std::clock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock), specifically:

> For example, if the CPU is shared by other processes, std::clock time
> may advance slower than wall clock. On the other hand, if the current
> process is multithreaded and more than one execution core is
> available, std::clock time may advance faster than wall clock.

Answer (score 1):

`std::clock` measures CPU time, not wall time (at least the gcc implementation, though I believe the MSVC implementation measures wall time). This is an excerpt from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock):

> Returns the approximate processor time used by the process since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related to the program's execution. To convert result value to seconds divide it by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.
>
> Only the difference between two values returned by different calls to std::clock is meaningful, as the beginning of the `std::clock` era does not have to coincide with the start of the program. `std::clock` time may advance faster or slower than the wall clock, depending on the execution resources given to the program by the operating system. For example, if the CPU is shared by other processes, `std::clock` time may advance slower than wall clock. On the other hand, if the current process is multithreaded and more than one execution core is available, `std::clock` time may advance faster than wall clock.

You can measure wall time with the `std::chrono` facilities:

```
auto Begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// ...
auto End = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << "Time for xxx: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(End - Begin).count() << std::endl;
```

and you will see the real speedup.

As a side note, I would say that your test is not thread safe, because `push_back` needs to modify the `end` position of your vector.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you're 2nd loop was slower is just from the overhead required for threading.  The work you're doing is very minimal and tends to be fast on its own.  Push_back is constant, the function just uses a pointer to the end of the container to add a new item then it updates the pointer to the 'end'.  I think if you were to put more complicated code into the loop you would start to see a difference.  I also noticed you never clear 'a' between loops, so you're adding an additional million items in to 'a' which might cause the 2nd loop (even if it wasn't threaded) to run slower.

I don't think you've misunderstood how to thread as much as you just overlooked the overhead (including creating, inti, context swtiches, ext) needed to do the threading.

This question seems to be rather common, but at the same time the answer to each one can be very different as many things go into threading (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80424/why-using-more-threads-makes-it-slower-than-using-less-threads).  In that link the answer was more broad, stating that thread speeds are very dependent on system performance such as CPU Resources, RAM resources, and network i/o resources).  This link: [Why is my multi-threading slower than my single threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960436/why-is-my-multi-threading-slower-than-my-single-threading)  shows that the OP was writing to the console, which is where the problem was (according to the link, the console class handles the thread syncronization so the code in the built in class is what was making the single thread run faster).

Answer (score 0):

It should also be said that what you're doing in the parallel loop is non-sensical and bound to cause run-time errors. There are two issues.

**First**

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int n=0; n<1000000000; ++n)
{   if(n%100000000 == 0) <some code>    }
```

only ever does anything 10 (**ten**) times. The compiler may optimise the loop variable `n` away and you're left with code equivalent to

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
{   <some code>   }
```

which only benefits from parallelism if `<some code>` is very computational demanding. So, you're actually **not testing anything**.

**Second**, and more seriously,

```
a.push_back(n);
```

is **not threadsafe**. That is, you must not call it (potentially) synchronously from different threads. Each call to `std::vector::push_back()` changes the state of the vector, i.e. its internal data, causing a race condition.

Finally, I should recommend to **not use OpenMP** for parallelism with C++, because it does not support/exploit C++ language features (such as templates) and is not even standardized for recent C++ standards.  Instead use something like [tbb](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/), which is designed for C++.