# Sending data over sockets is slower with concurrent threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Below I have an application where I am trying to send as much data in the fastest way possible using C# sockets. 10 seconds after the data has been started I stop the data sending and wait for a console key, also writing to the console how many requests were sent.

When setting the amount of threads to 1 I was reaching much higher requests. Here are the logs

```
Attempt 1    => 86873
Attempt 2    => 107324
Attempt 3    => 97426
Attempt 4    => 94720
Attempt 5    => 97927
Attempt 6    => 94327
Attempt 7    => 94791
```

As you can see, its peaking between 80,000 and 110,000 there about. When setting it to anything higher than 1 (I tried 1 and 2) it's not even hitting 80,000, its reaching about 70-75 thousand in the 10 seconds. My thoughts were more threads = more data sent, as its doing more work behind the scenes? Can anyone give me some information on this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RDOS
{
    public class ThreadHandler
    {
        private int count = 0;
        private int threadCount = 3;
        private List<Thread> _threads = new List<Thread>();

        private string _ip;
        private int _port;

        public int RequestsSent;
        public int RequestsFailed;
        public DateTime Started;

        public ThreadHandler()
        {
            Console.Write("IP: ");
            _ip = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Port: ");
            _port = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("sending data to " + _ip + " on port " + _port);

            Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OnBackgroundThread));
            backgroundThread.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
            {
                _threads.Add(new Thread(new ThreadStart(OnThread)));
            }

            foreach (Thread thread in _threads)
            {
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        public void OnBackgroundThread()
        {
            Started = DateTime.Now;

            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - Started;
                Console.WriteLine("Sent " + RequestsSent + " requests (running for " + span.TotalSeconds + ")");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public void OnThread()
        {
            IPEndPoint RHost = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_ip), _port);

            using (Socket socket = new Socket(RHost.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp))
            {
                socket.Blocking = true;

                while (true)
                {
                    RequestsSent++;
                    byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fwkdkskdsksk");
                    socket.SendTo(buf, SocketFlags.None, RHost);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about sockets but I assume this could be a problem `socket.Blocking = true;`

Comment: Dude, your measuring code has a very big flaw, `RequestsSent` must be at least marked as `volatile`, else .net will cache the value between calls, so multiple threads will see previous values and thus the counter is not working as you expect. Even with volatile it will miss some values, better lock the value before updating it.

Comment: Writing to `Console` also causes the threads to synchronize.    [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960436/why-is-my-multi-threading-slower-than-my-single-threading)

Comment: @Amy I can't see any `Console` writing in the thread method

Comment: @Amy that's only on the thread where I write to the console, would that effect the other threads?

Comment: You're right, I misread the code and thought `ThreadHandler` was in a thread.

Comment: `namespace RDOS`... hmmm.

Comment: @Gusman also `++` is not thread safe too. to Josh, a `Interlocked.Increment(ref RequestsSent)` would fix that.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, totally correct, Interlocked.Increment would be the best solution.

Comment: Your sending far to little data for this test give any meaningful results. Send a massive image file or something, to make sure threads are all (trying) to run at the same time. You can use monitoring tools to watch connection behaviors as the try to compete (like with socket.Block true and false).

Comment: Network Monitoring Tool https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533.aspx

Comment: You dont really need a separate thread for OnBackgroundThread(), that logic can be put in the constructor... I would also rename ThreadHandler to MultiThreadedSocket or something. Also, backgroundThread and OnBackgroundThread should be renamed to backgroundThreadWorker and BackgroundThread or something (there is lingo for it, as with any Microsoft tech, theyre conventions should always be followed, makes code more self documenting and they're really good at naming conventions (Win32 libraries had pretty big function names (like sentences) but now they use a consistency. ie PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain by "++ is not thread safe", do you mean the increment operator in general is not, or writing to a thread-shared value type in general?

Comment: @SamusArin The increment operator, that operator is shorthand for `var temp = x + 1; x = temp;`, if `x` updates between the two instructions the updated value will get overwritten by the `x = temp` step. `Interlocked.Increment` uses native code to make those two steps atomic so `x` can't be updated while the operation is running.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh so if some function for **`x`** was used instead of **`++`**, call it  **`NegativeInverse(x) { return  -sqrt(x^2)*sqrt(-x^2) / (-x)^3 }`** then there shouldn't be any kind of race condition or anything that would make **`x`** unsafe if it is re-entrant?

Comment: @SamusArin kindof, the `x` inside `NegativeInverse` is safe because all the number types in .net are immutable are copied when sent to the function so the function works only on a local copy, not the shared instance. However doing `y = NegativeInverse(y)` is not safe because the value of `y` could be updated between the calling of `NegativeInverse` and the return of the function.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for clarifying... I figured a race exits for any L-value assignment operation of a shared variable, just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides [the thread safety error which is causing you to get lower than actual numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806618/c-sharp-slower-with-multiple-threads#comment74652248_43806618), while you may have multiple threads but you still only have one network adapter, that likely is where your bottleneck is.

Throwing more CPU power at a I/O bound problem will not get you faster I/O, in fact most of the time it will cause you to have slower I/O due to the overhead introduced from the locking the OS has to do to serialize access to the I/O device. The only way to get faster I/O is to get faster hardware.

Comment: Would I be better off just running 1 thread then? Also, how would I go about fixing the thread safety error, locking the whole thread method?

Comment: Replace `RequestsSent++;` with `Interlocked.Increment(ref RequestsSent);` to fix the thread safety error. As for the threading, I would  start with 1 and then slowly go up and mesure the rate and see where the sweet spot is.